# Deploying COM libraries with a C# application using ClickOnce

Tags: c#, com, clickonce

I need to deploy a C# application that is downloaded using ClickOnce. The application is 64bit and I need to deploy the 64bit Zebra printer library that contains a COM Object.

1. I am using VS 2013 Pro.
2. The application is targeted for .NET V4
3. When I include the libraries in the project with "Build Action" = "Content", and "Copy to Output Directory" = "Copy if newer" the application fails to install, complaining that the libraries already exist.
4. The target PC is 64 bit and has the latest drivers and the user assumes that the drivers are 64 bit.
5. I had the same issue until I installed the relevant SDK example and it worked for me.

How do configure VS so that I can distribute the required libraries?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean ClickOnce by click-to-install?

Comment: Yes (I think so!), i.e. I double click setup.exe or a .application file.

Comment: Does [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165432.aspx) help?

Comment: Hi D Stanley, that helped a lot. Thanks very much for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the issue was how the libraries were originally imported into the project. Using another application that uses the same library I managed, by trial and error, to import the libraries that I needed and install correctly.

**Edit:** The article that D Stanley pointed out in the comments above solved the issue I was having.

**Edit 2:** The actual solution to the above problem is that you also need to register the library in the directory that has the .sln file in. Then the click once install compiler is able to pull in the file and register it on the target machine.